# Animation on the border of the button so that it completes when hovering

Tags: html, css, animation, border

Initially the border is not visible, but when hover over the button I want the border to be visible and makes a round and complete like a rectangle.

```css
.btn{
  border:0;
  background-color:transparent;
  height: 20px;
  width:auto;
}

.btn :hover{
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1.5px solid red;
  background-color: purple;
  cursor:pointer;
  
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<button class="btn">Hi!there.</button>
</body>

</html>
```

So, I didn't even tried, just couldn't figured out how to do that animation. I just wrote something as a code hope you get the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```css
.button {
  background: #eee;
  border-style: hidden;
  border: 3px transparent; #d0d0d0;
  transition: border 1s;
}

.button:hover {
  border: 3px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>


<head>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stack.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <button class="button">Hi!there.</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This was no the  answer I was hoping, I wanted the border to complete when hovered over, like ------ goes like this and not readily completed

Comment: okay I will edit it

Comment: like this is what you intend?